# Dynamically display the status message from services Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, mbprogresshud

I want to display the message dynamically from a service when a button is clicked

The following is the dynamic message getting from service

```
 HelloMessage =     {
 Message = "Successfully Registered with your Mail. Thank You. ";
 };
```

Am using MBProgressHUD. How to display success or error message with MBProgressHUD. Following is my code.TIA

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [HUD hide:YES];
   [HUD removeFromSuperview];
   HUD=nil;

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.responseData = nil;

    NSMutableArray *sdf = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"DataTable"];
    NSMutableArray * myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary * myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    if (([(NSString*)sdf isEqual: [NSNull null]])) {

     //Dynamic Message showing error status from a service


    }else {

        for (int i=0; i<[sdf count]; i++) {
            myDict=[sdf objectAtIndex:i];
            [myArray addObject:[myDict objectForKey:@"HelloMessage"]];

        }

      // Dynamically display the success message from service
 }

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [HUD hide:YES];
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];
    HUD=nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first in your viewcontroller

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) MBProgressHUD *hud;
```

on where you need to display the HUD, put the following code :

```
    _hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    _hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
    _hud.labelText = @"your success or failure message put here";
    [_hud hide:YES afterDelay:1.5];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this easily customisable [cool control](https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages) over `MBProgressHUD` for showing error/success/info message as per your need. But don't forget to include a bridging header as its written in Swift and you are working with Objective-C.

Use `MBProgressHUD` for showing loading and `SwiftMessages` for showing your messages.